# ARCORE geospatial API - authentication error

Tags: geospatial, arcore

I am running the ARCORE geospatial quickstart sample APP for Android. However, when I run the APP, the following error is displayed 'There was an error state error, check that you have a valid authentication for the ARCORE api

I have ensured my credentials enable ARCORE api and the API key has unrestricted access. I have also updated manifest to include my API key.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I used a phone not in the list of certified ARCORE list. I changed my phone and the error message disappeared